# add object into python's set collection and determine by object's attribute

Tags: python, set

I have a `Person` class like this:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Person {}>'.format(self.name)
```

I want to add some instances of this class to a set, like this:

```
tom = Person('tom', 18)
mary = Person('mary', 22)
mary2 = Person('mary2', 22)

person_set = {tom, mary, mary2}
print(person_set)
# output: {<Person tom>, <Person mary>, <Person mary2>}
```

As you can see, there are 2 Marys in the set. How can I make it so that `Person` instances with the same age are considered the same person, and only added to the set once?

In other words, how can I get a result of `{<Person tom>, <Person mary>}`?

Comment: So, as an example, `Frank, age 19` would be the same as `Heather, age 19` if you are just comparing by age?

Comment: yes,only the first one be added into the set will be stored

Comment: @sashimi, then you need a dictionary with age as key, Person object as value.

Comment: @spinlok i think he just needs a `__hash__` implemented.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

When a new object is being added to a python set, the hash code of the object is first computed and then, if one or more objects with the same hash code is/are already in the set, these objects are tested for equality with the new object.

The upshot of this is that you need to implement the [`__hash__(...)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__hash__) and [`__eq__(...)`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__eq__) methods on your class. For example:

```
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

    def __eq__(self, other):
        return self.age == other.age

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.age)

    def __repr__(self):
        return '<Person {}>'.format(self.name)

tom = Person('tom', 18)
mary = Person('mary', 22)
mary2 = Person('mary2', 22)

person_set = {tom, mary, mary2}
print(person_set)
# output: {<Person tom>, <Person mary>}
```

However, you should think very carefully about what the correct implementation of `__hash__` and `__eq__` should be for your class. The above example works, but is non-sensical (e.g. in that both `__hash__` and `__eq__` are defined only in terms of age).

Comment: thanks~this is what I want,I know it is weird.the class like **Person** which I will use is very simple.so it doesn't matter wheather overwrite or not.I know it's undesirable ^_^,I will use it carefully

Comment: Why does python even require specifying the `__eq__` method, if it's already doing the comparison of the value specified in `__hash__` ?

Comment: I answered my own comment - https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-hashable 

`__hash__` is for the lifetime value of the "object", `__eq__` is for comparing with other objects. You still need both to do comparison

Comment: https://hynek.me/articles/hashes-and-equality/ is a good article for more background