# hash method implementation not working along set() [Python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, object, hash, set

I am implementing a hash function in an object and as my hash value for such object I use the username hashed value, i.e:

```
class DiscordUser:
    def __init__(self, username):
        self.username = username

    def __hash__(self):
        return hash(self.username)
```

The problem arises when adding such objects to the hash set and comparing them with the exact same username as input for the constructor, i.e:

```
user = DiscordUser("Username#123")

if user in users_set:
    # user is already in my users_set, such condition is NEVER MET, dont understand why

else:
    # add user to users_set, this condition is met ALWAYS
    users_set.add(user)
```

Why the hash funcion is not working as properly, or what im doing wrong here?

Comment: According to all the code shown in your question `user` is only in `users_set` at the end of the script which is after `if user in users_set:`. In that case the first if-branch can never be taken. Perhaps there is some code missing which demonstrates your actual problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hash function is working properly, `set` membership uses `__hash__()`, but if two objects have the same hash, `set` will use the `__eq__()` method to determine whether or not they are equal. Ultimately, `set` guarantees that no two elements are equal, not that no two elements have equal hashes. The hash value is used as a first pass because it is often less expensive to compute than equality.

## Why?

There is no guarantee that any two objects with the same hash are in fact equal. Consider that there are infinite values for `self.name` in your `DiscordUser`. Python uses siphash for hashing `str` values. Siphash has a finite range, therefore collisions must be possible.

Be careful about using a mutable value as input to `hash()`. The hash value of an object is expected to be the same for its lifetime.

Take a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10547584/4583620) for some nice info about `set`s, hashing, and equality testing in Python.

---

**edit**: Python uses [siphash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SipHash) for `str` values since 3.4